# youtube android api error render on android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-youtube-api

I program an app android to view youtube . I have a problem with android studio. I was copy YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar to folder libs and code in java is fine , but in the xml is has error

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
```

Tip: Try to build the project.

I was try to build project but it have the same error. Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Please help :D Tks all

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you adding the fragment programatically in your code like this:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment videoStreamingPlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    videoStreamingPlayerFragment.initialize(mDevKey, new PlayerInitializedListener());

    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                  
    ft.replace(R.id.Container, videoStreamingPlayerFragment);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

in case you want to use the View instead of the fragment you could add it with the function addView:

```
YouTubePlayerView youtubeView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
        youtubeView.initialize(mDevKey, new PlayerInitializedListener());
        FrameLayout youtubeContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.YoutubeContainer);

        youtubeContainer.addView(mYoutubeView);
```

The activity where you do the operation must extend YouTubeBaseActivity